# Why setState() method not working despite making related variable nullable

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage>{

  Gender? selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: mainColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          'BMI Calculator'
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: ReusableCard(
                        colour: selectedGender == Gender.male ? activeCardColor : inactiveCardColor,
                      cardChild: IconContent(
                        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.mars,
                        label: 'MALE',
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender == Gender.male;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),`
```

`

setState() method isn't updating the card color despite setting Gender? selectedGender to nullable, why is this happening?

I have tried changing `selectedGender` to `late` yet it gives the `LateInitializationError`, I wanted the `colour: selectedGender == Gender.male ? activeCardColor : inactiveCardColor` to set color to inactiveCardColor (this is working fine) and then setState() method should change it to active one upon Tap (that's not working).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change `selectedGender == Gender.male` to `selectedGender = Gender.male`inside the setstate

```
setState(() {
   selectedGender = Gender.male;
});
```

Comment: Yes, as @Moony-Stary suggested you were comparing the variable `selectedGender` to the value `Gender.male` which is returning true, it's like writing the line
```
true;
false;
1 == 1;
```
which doesn't do anything actually.

`selectedGender = Gender.male;` is actually assigning a new value to the variable. Hope this explains.

Answer (score 0):

Please assign value properly

```
setState(() {
                    selectedGender = Gender.male;
                  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your `setState()` method again. The code there `selectedGender == Gender.male;` doesn't assign selectedGender a new value, and so because the state remains same, state is not updated. Use `=` instead of `==` to update the value of selectedGender variable.

```
setState(() {
   selectedGender = Gender.male;
});
```